# File association change doesn't work in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, file-association

I have an enduser that is a developer and thus has a custom program he made to open a file our software generates.  When he double clicks the .zzz file, it opens up an older iteration of the software.  When he went to Open With, drilled down to where the program is selected it, chose always open, it fails.  It still opens the older version as on the title bar there is a software version number.  I tried and retried several times and no matter what it still opens the old version.

I can manually load the new version and it correctly shows the version number in the title, but for some reason, the double clicking the file does not work.

He is a standard user thus when I load the registry, I am running as administrator using my domain admin account rather than local administrative account.

Is there another spot in the registry where these associations are stored?  I didn't see anything under users GUIDs, but HKCR, the .zzz is empty, even if i manually populate it, nothing changes.  I searched for the program and found only things in the MRU.

I am completely befuddled at this point and any assistance in knowing how to manually delete the associations there and replace it with the new executable, and how to prevent this from happening again is appreciated.

Much thanks.

Comment: Has he tried uninstalling the prior version and re-installing the new one?

Comment: It is a self-contained executable he created in Visual Studio.  Nothing has been installed.

Comment: Why isn't this user asking us for help themselves?  It is really hard to help people through a game of telephone.  "When he went to Open With, drilled down to where the program is selected it, chose always open, it fails. " - *This statement does not really tell us much.*

Comment: @ramhound not too sure why it makes a difference if I, in IT am asking the question, opposed to the enduser himself.  But, that being said, if he right clicks the file he wants to have opened with his customised programme, he chose (and I did the same), `Open with > Choose another App >  Tick Always Use > More Apps > Look in PC > scroll to the updated executable > and click Open`  it fails.  The older program that he associated still opens.  I do not see that anywhere in the registry.  I dont see anyway to remove the now two viewer options in the file association dialogue.  So we're both stuck

Comment: "The older program that he associated still opens." - Has attempted to find this copy his program's executable and replace it with the newer version of the program?

Comment: That is the problem, he nor I can find the original as he has local copies and copies on the server where the finished compiled code goes.  I don't see reference in the registry as to which one it is.  The file association dialogue does not show path of what is currently there as it just shows the program name/icon.